# How can I interpet an integer as a different type in python on a binary level

Tags: python

I want to do the following:

```py
a = 4
b = 7

result = int([a, b]) # Result is 1031 or 1796 depending on the endianness
```

So essentially lay out two unsigned integers next to each other, as one byte, and interpret the region as a two-byte unsigned integer.

Is this possible given python's generic `int`?

Comment: Which result do you want, 1031 or 1796?

Comment: Can you clarify how an unsigned integer should be packed into one byte exactly? You're just allowing values up to 256? Even then, how exactly do you get to 1031 or 1796?

Comment: Generally something like `unpack('I', pack('HH', 4, 7))` is a possible approach, but that ends up with a different value…

Comment: Is this basically what you want to do in a class? `int(bin(4)[2:].zfill(8) + bin(7)[2:].zfill(8), 2)`

Comment: do you mean `a<<8 | b` or `b<<8 | a` ?

Comment: @Sadap Yes, can you explain how that works? I'm not very well versed in byte shifting.

Comment: @UncreativeName https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/bitwise_operators_example.htm I can make you a better explanation in a hour if you need, im in an exam at the moment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use bitwise operations:
`a << 8 | b`

**Explanation:**

First, `a << 8` is evaluated. It's a left shift, so all the bits are going 8 places to the left:

```
0000 0000 0000 0100
          ↙↙↙ ↙↙↙
        ↙↙↙ ↙↙↙
      ↙↙↙ ↙↙↙
   ↙↙↙ ↙↙↙
↙↙↙ ↙↙↙
0000 0100 0000 0000
```

Then the `|` operator (bitwise or) is evaluated.

```
   0000 0100 0000 0000  #<= a<<8
OR 0000 0000 0000 0111  #<= b
----------------------
=  0000 0100 0000 0111  #<= a<<8 | b, decimal 1031
======================
```

The result of the bitwise OR ist an `1` wherever at least one operand has an `1` at this place. Here it's used to "merge" the two numbers together. Because the left byte of `b` is all `0` it doesn't affect the left byte of the first operand and vice versa.